# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational

Tags: csv

I try to use internal tool to export and import users form Active Directory to Active Directory
I login as admin of windown server
Tool request specify the AD target as FQDN include OU so I create new Organization on AD to test like image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JB82o.png)
I use this DC and OU add to tool and export then log show error

```
2023-04-25 10:22:41,738 ERROR- Test-DEMO\vmadmin: Exception occurred while getting users in OU: OU=TestImport,DC=Test-demo,DC=com; search filter: (&(objectCategory=user)); scope: Subtree; atttributes: samAccountName,employeeNumber,homePhone,userPrincipalName
2023-04-25 10:22:41,738 ERROR- Test-DEMO\vmadmin: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8007203A): The server is not operational.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.get_AdsObject()
   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher.FindAll(Boolean findMoreThanOne)
   at GAD.ADToolBox.LDAPHelper.SearchContainerForAll(String containerDistinguishedName, String ldapSearchFilter, SearchScope searchScope, ADToolBoxConfigurationEntry configurationEntry, String[] customAttributes) in C:\projects\GT\GADToolBox\GAD.ADToolBox\LDAPHelper.cs:line 2261
   at GAD.ADToolBox.LDAPHelper.GetUsersInContainer(String containerDistinguishedName, String ldapSearchFilter, SearchScope searchScope, ADToolBoxConfigurationEntry configurationEntry, Boolean includeAccessRules, String[] customAttributes) in C:\projects\GT\GADToolBox\GAD.ADToolBox\LDAPHelper.cs:line 1039
   at GAD.ADToolBox.LDAPHelper.GetUsersInContainer(String containerDistinguishedName, String ldapSearchFilter, SearchScope searchScope, String[] customAttributes) in C:\projects\GT\GADToolBox\GAD.ADToolBox\LDAPHelper.cs:line 990
   at Safewhere.UserMigrator.Domain.ExportUserTask.ExecuteTask() in D:\source\Safewhere User Migrator\Safewhere.UserMigrator.Domain\ExportUserTask.cs:line 38
```

Can help me to resolve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.